# Why is the detection of gravitational waves so significant?

Tags: general-relativity, experimental-physics, gravitational-waves, ligo

LIGO has announced the detection of gravitational waves on 11 Feb, 2016. I was wondering why the detection of gravitational waves was so significant?

I know it is another confirmation of general relativity (GR), but I thought we had already confirmed GR beyond much doubt. What extra stuff would finding gravitational waves teach us? Is the detection of gravitational waves significant in and of itself, or is there data which can be extracted from the waves which will be more useful?

Comment: Obligatory reference: http://smbc-comics.com/index.php?db=comics&id=2088#comic

Comment: PHD Comics has a nice take on it: http://www.phdcomics.com/comics/archive.php?comicid=1853

Comment: We now have sonar for stellar objects. We listened to a pair of black holes ripping into each other at the speed of light 1.2 billion light years away.  The atmosphere of our planet was only barely forming when this happened - it's well outside of our galaxy. We're going to watch the universe unfold around us by listening while it speaks. Kind of a big deal.

Comment: I've always found the metaphor of space a sheet with objects on it perplexing - the reason it sounds intuitive is because of our notion of gravity pulling things down!

Comment: @Nacht : Obligatory [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/895/).

Comment: @EricTowers Obligatory [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/1642/).

Comment: I had assumed that 'because it might let us "see" dark matter' was one of the reasons.

Comment: I bet military are thinking how to use it for even more powerful weapons...

Comment: It's not as significant as not detecting them

Comment: re: PHD Comics.  I hate the rubber sheet analogy because I always ask, 'What makes the bowling ball fall into the sheet?'  :)

Comment: The main long term benefit seems to be that its a new mode to scan the universe, completely different from E-M waves.

Comment: @Nacht, Jiminion The way I try to avoid the idea that gravity pulls objects down into the sheet is that the whole analogy would still work if you flipped the whole picture over, so that things pulled up instead. Objects move in circles around the sheet because those are the geodesics (locally straight lines), not because they are pulled by some 4D gravity force. The distortions themselves are caused by mass; think of it as pulling a blanket around yourself (which works equally well up or down).

Comment: @MarioCarneiro, that definitely helps me think about it, but there's more than one aspect that seems to be presupposing gravity... like the fact that the objects push down upon the sheet and cause the dent. Maybe they're not being pushed down, maybe they're just positioned such that their center of mass is aligned with the plane?

Comment: @Nacht The blanket analogy is meant to cover this case. Mass pulls on the sheet, not by pushing up or down (this is just an artifact of the embedding into an extra unphysical dimension) but by pulling it inward, causing it to bunch up like grabbing a section of a blanket and scrunching it up. This causes bends in the 'material' of space, which cause otherwise straight lines on the surface to curve around the pinch point.

Comment: I think the discovery strengthens the relativistic view of gravity as "the curvature of spacetime", and leaves detection of "graviton" quanta (which I believe are still entirely hypothetical) less important.  (The late John Barrow, a Cambridge physicist "just down the hall from Stephen Hawking", had recently described waves in our future as becoming particles in our past, but I believe he was referring to probability waves, whereas the gravitational ones are physical.)

Answer (score 173, accepted):

**Gravitational waves are qualitatively different from other detections.**

As much as we have tested [GR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity) before, it's still reassuring to find a completely different test that works just as well. The most notable tests so far have been the shifting of Mercury's orbit, the correct deflection of light by massive objects, and the redshifting of light moving against gravity. In these cases, spacetime is taken to be static (unchanging in time, with no time-space cross terms in the metric). Gravitational waves, on the other hand, involve a time-varying spacetime.

**Gravitational waves provide a probe of strong-field gravity.**

The tests so far have all been done in weak situations, where you have to measure things pretty closely to see the difference between GR and Newtonian gravity. While gravitational waves themselves are a prediction of linearized gravity and are the very essence of small perturbations, their *sources* are going to be very extreme environments -- merging black holes, exploding stars, etc. Now a lot of things can go wrong between our models of these extreme phenomena and our recording of a gravitational wave signal, but if the signal agrees with our predictions, that's a sign that not only are we right about the waves themselves, but also about the sources.

**Gravitational waves are a new frontier in astrophysics.**

This point is often forgotten when we get so distracted with just finding *any* signal. Finding the first gravitational waves is only the beginning for astronomical observations.

With just two detectors, [LIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIGO) for instance cannot pinpoint sources on the sky any better than "somewhere out there, roughly." Eventually, as more detectors come online, the hope is to be able to localize signals better, so we can simultaneously observe electromagnetic counterparts. That is, if the event causing the waves is the merger of two neutron stars, one might expect there to be plenty of light released as well. By combining both types of information, we can gain quite a bit more knowledge about the system.

Gravitational waves are also good at probing the physics at the innermost, most-obscured regions in cataclysmic events. For most explosions in space, all we see now is the afterglow -- the hot, radioactive shell of material left behind -- and we can only infer indirectly what processes were happening at the core. Gravitational waves provide a new way to gain insight in this respect.

Comment: "if the signal agrees with our predictions, that's a sign that not only are we right about the waves themselves, but also about the sources" -- conversely, and just as importantly, if the signal does not agree with predictions then it shows that we are wrong about something and can consider which of the assumptions to discard.

Comment: Also, it's a breathtaking technological achievement.

Comment: @Mew Oh, is that what you want to hear? In that case, "STAR TREK WARP DRIVE FINALLY IN REACH!!! In other news, the Bears still suck."

Comment: I've a dual feeling from the answer. On the one hand the answer is big, enthusiastic, and detailed. On the other hand… it explains almost nothing! I mean, it mentioned problems of detectors, possible waves sources, the past of the GR, and its relation to waves… But with relation to the question it basically says, that waves somehow could give additional information about an explosion. How? What kind of information? Reading the answer gave me nothing new, and I am not even a physicist by the way.

Comment: Doesn't the minuscule magnitude of the signal kind of/completely negate most of the usefulness of detecting this, though? You have two objects so large that they tear a hole in space-time crashing into each other at relativistic speeds, and... we measured a ripple that was *1 thousandth the size of a proton*. That's an incredible feat of engineering, but from a scientific standpoint, it seems that gravitation waves are too low fidelity to be of much serious use. `I feel something!  It could be a pebble, or it could be a mountain, but I feel something!`  Still don't see how that's... useful.

Comment: @Hi-Angel that's  a good question. There is a lot you can do with gravitational waves. I'll give one example. Neutron stars are very compact objects. To first approximation they are like a star sized nucleus--this isn't really true but good enough for an initial picture. We don't understand their internal structure, and because they are small and electrically neutral you can't point a telescope at one. With gravitational waves you can "hear" a neutron star and learn about its structure (more technically the equation of state). Here is a paper that discusses that: http://arxiv.org/abs/0901.3258

Comment: @HopelessN00b Even if it's currently as useless as you say, the answer does explicitly mention future improvements ("as more detectors come online..."). Seems like the first instrument to detect a phenomenon is always going to be relatively basic; why not take it as a sign of what could be possible? I'm sure you'd have been pretty underwhelmed looking through the first telescope too.

Comment: @Jefromi There is that, but the question I'm asking about isn't one of what we can detect now, it's about the fundamentally minuscule magnitude of the signal itself.  Looking through the first telescope, I wouldn't be trying to see something ~4 orders of magnitude smaller than a subatomic particle.  I might be underwhelmed, sure, but the potential of being able to see further and further away are pretty obvious... the potential of detecting something as small and lo-fi as gravity waves seems... much harder to determine.

Comment: I do not understand your last paragraph. As I have just asked in a question, how do GW probe the physics at the core? To do this they should escape from i.e black hole, how do they?

Comment: Yet another test: the twin pulsars.

Comment: Wouldn't the events that these detectors can see most likely be very old?  I wouldn't think black holes collide as much now compared with the past.  And I don't think there are many other events (maybe supernovae, but we can see them) that would produce such big waves.

Comment: This answer is a little misleading when it says that so far there were no tests done in strong field. In fact there have already been many tests in strong field, long before the gravitational wave detection: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tests_of_general_relativity#Strong_field_tests:_Binary_pulsars . These trajectories are spectacularly different from Newtonian prediction.

Comment: @mpv While the *surface* of a pulsar is mildly strong-field, as a system of two orbiting masses even the double pulsar is very weakly relativistic. The orbital separation is $10^5$ or so Schwarzschild radii, and the orbital velocity is a fraction of a percent the speed of light. This may be $100$ times stronger than the relativistic effect on Mercury's precession, but it is still small. Note the theoretical predictions (which match observations) behind the Hulse-Taylor binary were done in the 70s, a good three decades before we could do strong-field numerical relativity.

Comment: Jefromi: FWIW it wasn't *literally* the first telescope, but within a couple of years of the first and using the same design Galileo discovered three moons of Jupiter, and a week later a fourth. This was more than "underwhelming", it was like the first time you pick up a rock and find bugs. Within a year of that, observing the phases of Venus demonstrated that in any geocentric model it "crosses the orbit" of the Sun. So what observations are gravitational waves going to give us in 2-3 years? Frankly, physics is all very well but what has it done for me *lately*? ;-)

Comment: Btw I don't think LIGO is trivial or useless by any means, I just don't think the near-immediate impact of even that rudimentary telescope can be ignored. It's the opposite of being a poster child for the notion that "well, it's early days yet, these things take time to develop".

Answer (score 77):

Chris' answer provides an excellent explanation as to why gravitational waves are useful to detect in general. Here's my take (as someone who works in the theory of black holes) on what is particularly interesting about the signal that was announced yesterday. Many of my thoughts are taken from the official NSF press conference and from colloquia at my institution.

**The Event Itself**

Numerical analysis of the gravitational wave event that was measured on September 14, 2015, has revealed a great deal about the nature of the event that took place.

The following is a figure from the LIGO report which shows the gravitational wave signal:

[image]

([source](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1602/1602.03837.pdf))

The red line in each graph is the gravitational wave signal measured from the observatory in Hanford, Washington. The blue line is the gravitational wave signal measured from the observatory in Livingston, Louisiana. The top left graph shows the Hanford signal alone, the top right graph shows the Livingston signal overlaid with the Hanford signal (look how nicely they match up, proving that this was not a local source of noise but rather a signal being generated from some cosmic distance).

The left graph in the second row is most interesting. The light gray line essentially shows the signal, cleared of as much noise as possible (the equipment is so sensitive that all sorts of things can cause slight jitters in the waveform). The red line represents the waveform that would be predicted by the techniques of numerical general relativity for a system of two black holes spiraling into each other. It's no coincidence that the observed waveform (light gray) and predicted waveform (red) overlap so well.

There is, of course, a great deal of analysis that goes into checking the statistical significance of this data. Scientists at LIGO have found that within a statistically significant margin, this waveform was probably produced by a binary system of two black holes, each about thirty times as massive as the size of the sun.

Now, for the specifics as to what is interesting about this event.

**Black Holes In General**

Before yesterday, we had no direct evidence to show that black holes existed. We were fairly confident in the existence of black holes, but only through indirect measurements. This is the first ever direct measurement of a black hole—the objects in question are massive enough and compact enough that they almost surely must be black holes. What's more, the data fits perfectly our general relativistic predictions as to what kind of radiation will be released by a black hole merger. This is huge news—physicists never had complete evidence that black holes existed before yesterday, although the public might take it for granted. Black holes exist, *and they work the way we thought they did.* That's incredible!

**Types of Black Holes**

From an astrophysical perspective, this is quite interesting, because both of the inspiraling black holes were about 30 times as massive as the sun (henceforth referred to as having "30 solar masses"). Astrophysicists had no real compelling evidence for black holes in this mass range. It was assumed that we had black holes in the range of 3-20 solar masses, and the so-called "supermassive" black holes (which are millions, billions, of solar masses? I'm not an astrophysicist so I can't tell you). This is a fascinating astrophysical problem—the mass in a black hole needs to come from somewhere. What is the process by which a black hole of ~30 solar masses forms? From where does it take its matter? How massive is it when it first forms (from a star, perhaps?), and how much does it grow after it has already become a black hole?

Oh, and by the way, we haven't just confirmed the existence of two black holes of solar mass ~30. We've confirmed the existence of one black hole of 62 solar masses—the black hole remaining after the two have merged. Speaking of, let's talk a bit about that final black hole.

**Radiation**

The collective mass of the two black holes before they merged was ~65 solar masses. The mass of the final black hole was ~62 solar masses.

What that means is that 3 solar masses were radiated away in gravitational waves as the black holes merged. Not impressed? Well, here's some perspective: according to the NSF conference given yesterday, the power output of gravitational radiation during the last moments of the black hole merger was *more than the collective power output of every star in the universe combined.*

That's a lot of energy, very fast. What happens once that energy is released? Well...

**Ring-Down**

This is my personal favorite, but it's also the thing about which we have the least information. If you look again at the figure I included earlier in this response, at, say, the second graph in the left column, you'll notice that the pattern goes as follows:

Slight vibrations, increasing in amplitude in frequency, suddenly oscillating very quickly at a high amplitude, and then dying down to almost nothing.

That sudden increase in frequency is called a "chirp," and it's what LIGO was looking for. That chirp tells us everything we need to know about the black hole merger.

But what about what happens afterward? The exponential decay of the signal corresponds to the resulting black hole (with 62 solar masses) settling down into a stable state. The question of black hole stability is incredibly interesting, and the process by which a black hole settles down after some major perturbation (e.g. merging with another black hole) is a fascinating object of study.

Basically, if you hit a black hole, it rings. When you perturb a black hole away from its stable state, you create something called quasinormal modes—mathematical descriptions of the perturbation from equilibrium—which decay exponentially over time as the black hole approaches equilibrium.

The experimental signal does not contain much information about the ring-down. We can't glean much information about exactly how the black hole settles into a stable state—the process doesn't generate very strong gravitational waves, for one thing, and it happens very quickly.

But that's okay. In the figure, we can see it happen. We see two black holes merge, release *three solar masses* of radiation, and then settle down into a stable final state. That alone is incredibly exciting.

Oh, by the way, one parting thought: this black hole merger happened about a billion years ago. We're only getting its signal now.

Comment: What do you mean by "bottom left graph"? If you mean the one with "Residual" label, it's just a difference between measured (top) and predicted (middle), not the cleared signal.

Comment: I edited it to what I think is accurate, although I suppose it's possible I'm still incorrect. I was under the impression that the light gray line represents a cleaned signal (via approximation by sine-Gaussian wavelets), and that the red line represents the predicted signal. Am I incorrect? Are all three lines in the middle-left graph predicted signals?

Comment: These two gray lines are reconstructions using [matched filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matched_filter) technique, as said in the paper text just in the beginning of _II. Observation_.

Comment: [Here's the arxiv link](http://arxiv.org/abs/1602.03837) to the main paper (there are many other official places to get it). Note that the license is very liberal -- share the figure to your heart's content. It would be a good to include it here.

Comment: Silly question: do we know these waves are from Black Holes ? Is it correct to assume the assumption of black hole binary source is just because there is nothing else we know of in our current theoretical structure which allows such extreme energies? In principle, this could be a signal from something more exotic, beyond our standard gravitational example-set ?

Comment: This was a fun read, thank you. @JamesS.Cook: The fact that it fits the predictions so well makes it hard, I would think, to come up with something different. I assume the data is not interpretable without a rotational collapse event of 2 extremely dense 30 sun masses; for all we know these must be black holes. Something along these lines.

Comment: 3 solar masses escaped of 65 total masses!  That is very interesting given the conventional understanding of a black hole as being a singuarity with all mass squeezed to the center.  We know it can't be infinite density, do we even have a clue what that core consists of?  Normally stuff that goes in could never escape (save tiny Hawking radiation).  So then, what is the nature of the escaped mass and what happened to the cores of these masses?

Comment: I think there was already very strong direct evidence of black holes before the detection of gravitational waves. The stars near the center of our galaxy are orbiting something in the very center. This central object is invisible, very compact, but when you analyze the trajectories of the stars, the central object mass is over 4 million solar masses: https://youtu.be/duoHtJpo4GY?t=57 Something so massive could hardly be so small and dark.

Answer (score 56):

In additions to what Chris White lists, I'd like to point to the fact that, except for a few meteorites and some dust collected on the plates of satellites and rocks from Mars (and cosmic rays and a handful of neutrinos; thanks Ruslan and Kyle Oman), until now *all* information reaching us from the Universe — whether it is the Sun, the more distant planets, other stars, galaxies, CMB, etc, — has come to us in the form of electromagnetic radiation.

Gravitational waves is a whole new mode of gaining knowledge about the Universe. Both from objects where we *also* see radiation, but also for instance perhaps at some point inflation at the Big Bang, where using electromagnetic radiation we can't see further back than the CMB, 380,000 years after Big Bang (this is what the BICEP2 guys thought they saw two years ago, but it turned out to dust…).

Comment: Not only EM radiation: we also have some neutrino detectors.

Comment: And particles, e.g. cosmic rays.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I forgot about those.

Comment: Next step:  A gravity wave version of SETI

Comment: @StevenGubkin Detection of two solar mass aliens dancing?

Comment: @NathanK An alien lifeform sufficiently advanced may have a way of delaying the merge of black holes in a predictable fashion which to other forms of intelligent life sufficiently advanced to know it will realize not only that intelligent life exists but where it originates...

Answer (score 26):

Adding briefly to Chris' answer.

Gravitational waves are not obscured by anything. If detectors are made to work at lower frequencies (in space) then they can "see" gravitational waves originating from beyond the cosmic microwave background right back to the inflationary epoch.

Another thing that has become clear today is that binary mergers give a chirp that yield the masses of the merging components, but also gives accurate, independent distance estimates. These events are the equivalent of standard candles for EM waves - "standard sirens".

Comment: Are gravitational waves also not obstructed by gravitational wave detectors?

Comment: Yes. Of course it depends on the assumption that grav waves travel at the speed of light. If we can be more accurate in doing the measurements, i.e. From space with larger interferometers, we could also see dispersion if different freqs had different speeds. Also if we could catch some EM signature from the merger event (from plasma/gas also flowing in at near light speed we could compare speeds. Also if we could see optically some signal of where exactly it happened we'd get distance independently so could get speeds. Lots more fun to come.

Answer (score 18):

**Gravitational waves are a *major* component of phenomena like black hole mergers**

The [GW150914 gravitational wave event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave_observation#Black_hole_merger) is believed to be a merger of two black holes with estimated masses of 36+5/-4 and 29±4 solar masses. The final mass was 62±4 solar masses. If our current models are correct then the missing 3.0±0.5 solar masses (**5.3%**) were radiated away as gravitational waves, and that in only 0.2 seconds.

If we could not detect gravitational waves, then that 5% would be a major gap in our models. Now in this case we only know that the event happened *because* we detected the waves, but supposing we had observed some similar event in the electromagnetic spectrum, if we could not also detect the gravitational waves then it would be a big flaw in our observations of the event.

Answer (score 7):

With Gravitational Waves(GW) one can "know" that the Objects is there - detect it without "seeing"-visually, it just because the object has a mass.

Anything moving and having a mass is emitting GW - current detectors are sensitive only for objects with masses equal to mass of many Suns $2\times 10^{30} ~\rm{kg}$ (2 with 30 zeros).

Imagine one day may we have sensors-detectors able to detect movement of any objects with mass without seeing it ....

Comment: Moving is not enough. You need acceleration.

Comment: Moving _somewhat_ implies that acceleration happened at some point in the past. Similarly, constant stable movement _somewhat_ implies that deceleration hasn't happened yet.

Comment: Is acceleration needed? For instance, if a charged object moved rapidly past you, would you experience an electromagnetic wave? Similarly, if a black hole went whipping through the Solar System at a substantial fraction of the speed of light, wouldn't we experience a (single) gravitational wave?

Comment: @DanielGriscom: In the charged-object case, yes, you'd notice a one-time rise and fall of electric field.  **The object wouldn't be converting any of its kinetic energy into electromagnetic radiation**, though.  That's why it's not a wave.  As I understand it, grav waves work the same way.

Answer (score 4):

One interesting implication is that gravitational waves are considered to be more evidence of Inflation Theory, which is used to help explain the homogeneousness of the universe. If Inflation Theory is correct and space-time experienced an exponentially explosive expansion, that expansion need not have occurred at the same rate at every point in space.

In fact, the chances of that happening are apparently so astronomical as to be almost nil. As a result, a single point in space could expand at a completely different rate than that of its surrounding space-points (I've heard it compared to blowing up a balloon with a defect in it, so that the defect forms into a bubble on the surface when inflated).

As I understand it, you'd end up with a vast multitude- possibly even an infinite number of *alternate universes*, completely separate but still "attached" to the other universes. And with each universe possessing its own laws (or lack of?) to describe force, space, time, etc., the multiverse could theoretically exist forever, with a finite beginning but no end. (Source- one of my Engineering Physics professors)

@ Martin Thanks for the feedback! Admittedly I am largely ignorant of Inflation Theory, but I should add that my professor’s professor was a member of Guth’s team who helped developed the mathematics of Inflation Theory. In any case, my understanding is that although there are a variety of viable inflation theories, most serious models require the presence of gravitational radiation resulting from the Big Bang (termed Primordial Gravitational Waves). According to Guth’s theory, Inflation occurred just before the Big Bang, and when it stopped the energy present in the inflaton field was converted into heat and the Big Bang (and the granddaddy of all gravitational waves).

Inflation Theory is still pretty new (only about 40 years old or so?), so it stands to reason that any new theory being proposed nowadays is probably going to incorporate GR due to GR’s success. So I guess the short answer is that current Inflation models, which incorporate GR, require Primordial Gravitational Waves, and if Primordial Gravitational Waves exist, then Gravitational Waves exist.

Comment: This seems like a conflation of many different theories - especially I have never heard of your kind of multiverse being a consequence of any serious inflation theory. You might want to search for more sources. In addition, I don't see how gravitational waves, which are a simple consequence of perturbative general relativity should count as evidence towards a theory build on top of GR. It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: In reference to the original question concerning the usefulness of these finding- unless I'm mistaken, isn't this also the first chance we've had to confirm that gravity travels at light speed?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to answers given above, I'd like to add poweful theoretical argument.

As you know, there is Coulomb law, which states that static interaction between charged bodies behaves with distance $r$ as $r^{-2}$. It is long range law: if we touch one charge, then, according to this law, another one will feel the changing simultaneously. This point of view on electric interactions was completely changed when Maxwell have realized that the light, electric and magnetic interactions have the same nature; since the speed of light is finite, the Maxwell theory says us that if we touch one charge, then the information of changing of force - **electromagnetic field** - will propagate with finite speed - the speed of light.

This conception, conception of finiteness of all interactions, stays thus in all fundamental theories (according to modern point of view) independently on their nature; that is because this is the property of our space-time (this fact is fixed, for example, in explicit form of Lorentz transformations and causality principle and comes from the general axioms based on space-time symmetries).

General relativity theory, for example, is based on the statement that locally our space-time looks like Minkowski one, which forces the finiteness of gravitational interactions. In particular, General relativity theory equations on metric (Einstein equations), being linearized in absence of matter, formally coincide with those which we can obtain by constructing the free theory of massless particle helicity 2, starting from the global Poincare symmetry. The latter describes waves.

In the above point of view, detection of gravitational waves is something bigger than the checking of General relativity, opening the new method of astrophysical observations or one another way to check GR. It is checking the property of the spacetime which is the basis of all modern fundamental physics.

Answer (score 2):

A non-exhaustive list for some of the prospects:

**Neutron Star [equation of state](http://arxiv.org/abs/1503.05405)**

*Gravitational waves can be used to verify equation of state*

**[Gamma ray bursts'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma-ray_burst) inner structure**

*The dynamics of GRBs are still shrouded in mystery and nothing can really probe into the inner structure of GRBs like gravitational waves can*

**Speed of gravitational waves**

*One of the more obvious ones, but it still hasn't been established that the speed of gravitational waves is c (as it should be)*

**Testing theories of gravity**

*Technically, GR can be re-constructed by relaxing the assumptions and allowing for example [torsions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Cartan_theory). Maybe [Brans-Dicke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brans%E2%80%93Dicke_theory) theory is right?*

**Gravitons**

*Rather obvious*

Answer (score 1):

Since the electronmagnetic radiation was discovered, it changed the way how we communicate. So perhapes the gravitational radiation would bring something equal exciting.